# Howv to assign multiple result of query laravel php

Tags: php, database, eloquent, laravel-8

New to Laravel php and trying to find out solution of this,

```
$periods = Period::where('timetable_id', $id);
echo $periods;
```

giving this error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

i know why its giving this error but can not think of an alternate.

Comment: echo is used to print only string while in your case you are going to print object or an array so it's giving error. Try print_r() function to print array or object.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to `->get()` your results first. Also, since you'll get a Collection returned you'd need to use `dd()` (or `print_r`/`var_dump`) to output the results:

```
$periods = Period::where('timetable_id', $id)->get();
dd($periods);
```

More on [Building Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#building-queries)